# How to sort by date and time in data grid MUI X

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

in MaterialUI X data grid i have a column of date in the format of DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss and now (the defualt sort of the data grid) its sorting only by the date and the time of each day is messed up, wanted to know if there is a way to format so it will be date and time

[picture of the column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sRXR.png)

the data grid tag

```
<DataGrid
         rows={rows}
         columns={columns}
         autoPageSize
         components={{
           LoadingOverlay: Loader,
           Toolbar: QuickSearchToolbar,
           }}
         loading={listLoading}
         initialState={{
            sorting: {
               sortModel: [{ field: "Date", sort: "asc" }],
            },
         }}/>
```

i tried to use the docs of the MUIX data grid with the sortComparator example but didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default MUI sort date like a string. You should first convert it to ISO string, sort it and then use `valueFormatter` in column definition to show the format that you want.